# How to create middleware correctly?

Tags: laravel

Good day. I need to create a check, the id of the authorized user matches the entry from the user_id database. Help me please

Middleware CanEdit.php

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Middleware;

    use App\Models\Pass;
    use Closure;
    use Auth;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class CanEdit
    {
        /**
         * Handle an incoming request.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @param  \Closure  $next
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        {
            $user = Auth::user()->id;
            $editor = Pass::where('user_id', $user);
            if ($user == $editor) {
                return $next($request);
            }

            return redirect('home')->with('error','You have not access');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're never getting in the if condition because you're comparing two different classes here. If you need to check if only id's match, you could do it like this:

```
$user = Auth::user()->id;
$editor = Pass::where('user_id', $user)->first();
if ($user == $editor->user_id) {
  return $next($request);
}
```

But in my opinion, this check is not necessary. Assuming that `user_id` field is unique in Pass table, you don't need to check if id's match, you only need to check if record exists in `Pass` table:

```
$user = Auth::user()->id;
$editor = Pass::where('user_id', $user)->exists();
if ($editor) {
  return $next($request);
}
```

[exists()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#determining-if-records-exist) method simply returns boolean depending on if the record exists in the database or not.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
    if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
        return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
    } else {
        return redirect()->guest('login');
    }
}
return $next($request);
```